# Filter on Rows that are Within a Certain Timeframe

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of patients that were admitted and discharged from the hospital.  I am trying to find any patients that have an admission within 30 days of their previous discharge date.  So for example, I have the table:

| Name | Admission Date | Discharge Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Patient A | 1/1/2021 | 1/5/2021 |
| Patient A | 1/7/2021 | 1/10/2021 |
| Patient B | 2/1/2021 | 2/4/2021 |

Then I would want to have a table of:

| Name |
| --- |
| Patient A |

I am unsure of how to check the Discharge Date in row 1 against the Admission Date in row 2.  I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(discharge_date) over (partition by name order by admission_date) as prev_discharge_date
      from t
     ) t
where prev_prev_discharge_date > dateadd(day, -30, admission_date)
```